# Infinite loop Wordpress 301 redirect AWS CloudFront Load Balancer and LightSail

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-lightsail

I have a CloudFront, LightSail Load Balancer and LightSail instance hosting Wordpress under `/blog/` endpoint.

In Lightsail Load Balancer there is only HTTP option to connect to the instance so the traffic is now

HTTPS -> CloudFront -> HTTPS (different Domain) -> Origin Load Balancer -> HTTP -> LightSail Instance

The LightSail instance does a redirect to https with below settings in `wp-config.php`

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false)
       $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';

define('WP_HOME','https://www.test.com/blog');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://www.test.com/blog');
```

However this creates infinite loop.

How can we change the settings so it doesn't do the loop?